# NSFetchRequest core Data

Tags: uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am working with core data and saving a `NSMutableArray` to a transformable attribute , I use `NSFetchRequest` to prepare an `NSArray` which is intended to populate a `UITableView`, seems easy enough. I am also using an `NSFetchedResultsController` for section names.
Sections are populating the correct way using the titleForheaderInSection: 
My `UITableViewCell` is a differtent story. I fetch using the below code.

```
AppDelegate appDel = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
NSManagedObjectContext  context = appDel.managedObjectContext;
NSFetchRequest  fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription carEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:"CarDocType" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetch setEntity:carEntity];
docTypeToDisplay = [[appDel.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error]mutableCopy];
```

I am also having the user populate the section with a different number of rows in each section so in my cellForRowAtIndexPath i am doing this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString cellID = "Cell";
    UITableViewCell cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];

   cell.textLabel.text = [docTypeToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
  return cell;
}
```

when I try to return the cell from this call `cell.textLabel.text = [docTypeToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.section][indexPath.row]`
I am throwing an exception , it is looking for a string. So when I convert the `NSArray` to a `NSString` like so,

```
NSString carTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:",docTypeToDisplay];

NSString carTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:",carDocMset];
cell.textLabel.text = carTitle;
return cell;
```

I am getting the whole string not just the name , it looks like this

```
(entity: CarDocType; id: 0xd000000000040002 <x-coredata://AB5BF8F9-5166-4A11-AA69-30962EEAE745/CarDocType/p1> ; data: {  cardocumenttype    \\\"Driver License\\\"\\n)\  })
```

I just want the Driver License , I know I am missing something could someone tell me what it is please.

Regards
JZ

Comment: Why do you use an `NSArray` to fetch your results when you already have an `NSFetchedResultsController` fetching your results?

Comment: When you execute a fetchRequest, it returns an array of `NSManagedObject`. `docTypeToDisplay[indexPath.row]` returns `CarDocType` object. Considering Entity:`CarDocType` has an attribute: `driverLicense`, `NSString *driverLicense =docTypeToDisplay[indexPath.row].driverLicense `. Why are you not using `NSFetchedResultController` for `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` It is better to use relationship rather Array.

Comment: Also to create your `NSString` you do not provide an outlet in the format to insert your value, so even if you fetch your data it will not display. Change your syntax to set your string: `NSString *carTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", carDocMset];`

Comment: You seem to be rather confused about indexing into an array and fetched results controllers. The code you show looks like it should crash when you index into the array. Is that an actual copy&paste? You really should show details for the FRC and use it to populate the cells...

Comment: Thanks guys for input, I have been away from this , will take another look and use your feedback. Regards JZ